# Redefinition in anonymous struct/union Visual Studio 2013 ErrorC2658

Tags: visual-studio

Compiling old project on **Visual Studio 2013**
Getting below error

```
evntrace.h(521): error C2658: 
'_EVENT_TRACE_HEADER::DUMMYSTRUCTNAME': 
redefinition in anonymous struct/union
```

Cannot change the code.
**Is there any project settings in Visual Studio to fix this issue ?**

Answer (score 0):

Setting **Disable Language Extensions** /Za Fixed the problem
[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx)